# What are the recommended use cases for `react-hook-form` Controller vs useController?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I read the documentation and went through the examples, but I'm still really confused.

About `useController` [link](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller):

[image]

About `Controller` link:

[image]

**Question 1**

So, if I'm creating a reusable controlled input on my own, I should implement it with `useController` and just pass the `control` prop that the consumer will get from the `useForm()` call, right?

**Question 2**

And what is the `Controller` for? Is it just to use it with 3rd party libraries?

**Question 3**

Is it always one OR the other? Is there any case where both would be used at the same time?

**Question 4**

I guess that this sentence made me confused: *"This custom hook **powers** Controller"*. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is so late. I noticed it's been answered already on Github, so I just [commented there](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/7852#discussioncomment-3692813) with an additional two cents.

Essentially, I think `useController` is much easier to use and maybe in some cases necessary when you need to use a variable in an external handler that you cannot otherwise retrieve within the scoped `<Controller />`-rendered element. (See example in Github comment.)